# Javascript- it is syntax error but why

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

My code gives a error in my browser, but I don't know why can anyone help me please!

```
var naam = prompt("Genereer hier uw eigen cv, veel succes! Eerst uw naam graag.");

alert("Welkom " + naam );

console.log("Mijn naam is " + naam);

alert("Er zullen een paar vragen aan u gesteld worden. In de console ziet u de voortgang van uw cv.");


var wonend = prompt("Waar woont u op dit moment?");

console.log("en ik ben op dit moment wonend in " + wonend + ".");


var leeftijd = prompt("Wat is uw leeftijd?"); 

if(leeftijd <= 30); {

    console.log("Ik ben " + leeftijd + "jaar dus ik ben nog jong en energiek." );

}

else if(leeftijd >= 30 && <= 50); {

    console.log("Ik ben " + leeftijd + "jaar dus ik heb al wat ervaring en ben op zoek naar een stap hoger.");

}

else {

    console.log("Ik ben " + leeftijd + "jaar dus ik heb al de nodige ervaring, en wil graag aan het werk blijven.");

}

var vaardigheden = prompt("Wat zijn uw vaardigheden?"); 

console.log("Ik heb al flink wat vaardigheden opgebouwd zoals, " + vaardigheden + "en heb daar al de nodige ervaring in.");

alert("Bedankt voor het invullen van de vragen onder in uw console heeft u uw persoonlijke cv.");
```

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: `&& <= 50` And _what_ is less than or equal to 50?

Comment: @Juhana the message say: unexpected token

Comment: Chrome gives me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else", wich is not a totally obvious answer for a JS beginner. I would not lower this question.

Comment: You're allowed to put a `;` after an if, however, that's useless, you're saying if(_condition_) then 'um, doesn't matter, forget about it'.  Then you just have a block of code in braces that would be executed unconditionally, then you have an else, wait... else?  Huh?  I didn't expect else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all `if();{}` with `if(){}`.

Replace

```
if(leeftijd >= 30 && <= 50)
```

With

```
if(leeftijd >= 30 && leeftijd <= 50)
```

Comment: I've done that but it's not the solution for the error

Comment: @user3609762 didn't you forget about else?

Comment: THANKS!! I've added the word "leeftijd" in that line, now the code is oke!

Comment: @user3609762: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is customary to mark the answer that helped you as accepted. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

`if else` conditions cannot have `;` 
and comparisons have to always be `(value) (operator) (value)`.

```
if (leeftijd <= 30) {
    console.log("Ik ben " + leeftijd + "jaar dus ik ben nog jong en energiek." );
}
else if (leeftijd >= 30 && leeftijd <= 50) {
    console.log("Ik ben " + leeftijd + "jaar dus ik heb al wat ervaring en ben op zoek naar een stap hoger.");
}
```

Comment: Error is still there :( But thanks for that!

Comment: @user3609762: yeah, I still see a weird use of the `<=` operator there.

Comment: SO decided to go into maintenance-mode just when I was editing my answer. Either way, I've updated it to its entirety.